# matrix multiplication Parallelized implementation (OpenMP)

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I ran a matrix multiplication code serially and parallelized.There was no significant improvement with the parallel version.

```
    dimension =4000;

    //#pragma omp parallel for shared(A,B,C) private(i,j,k)
    {
    for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<dimension; j++){
           for(int k=0; k<dimension; k++){
             C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }       
    }
    }
```

Output:
                time ./a.out

```
real    4m58,760s
user    4m58,706s
sys     0m0,036s
```

for serial code (I put the #pragma... in a comment,rest of code is same) 
I got following output

```
real    4m51,240s
user    4m51,210s
sys     0m0,024s
```

Comment: Did you compile with `-fopenmp` flag? The pragma has no effect unless compiled with OpenMP. Also, you don't need the braces after the pragma since the for loop creates a new code block anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile code with `-fopenmp` for the pragma to work. Also, you don't need to comment the pragma to run without OpenMP, just don't compile with OpenMP.

With OpenMP: `gcc -fopenmp -o a.out code.c`
Without OpenMP: `gcc -o a.out code.c`

Comment: The OP should also compile with optimization. At the very least `-O2` but I recommend `-O3`. That's perhaps a more important lesson than using OpenMP.

Comment: With some compilers,  -O3 could give 80% of max achievable performance by automatically substituting a library call when it can detect a problem large enough to benefit from Openmp.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a (poorly chosen) educational example, please don't write your own matrix multiply and parallelize it. Getting near optimal performance from matrix multiplication involves other optimizations (vectorization, cache-blocking) which take time to get write and are hard to get correct.

As ever, "The best code is the code I don't have to write", so go grab a copy of a BLAS library (for instance, [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl) is now free).

I know it's more fun to write code than read a manual, but sometimes the latter is more productive!

Full disclosre: I work for Intel, but not on MKL.